How do I send parameters in a SignalR message and return a result using this parameters
I am wanting to use the ISingleClientProxy.InvokeAsync send a message SignalR client and wait for a response.  I can make this work until very easily using the following:
Server sends:
return await Clients.Client(connectionInfo.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync<string>("Test", default);

Client Returns:
this.hubConnection.On<string>("Test", () => { return "Successful"; });

My problem is I want to be able to send a parameter to the client and have it do something with it.
Something like this
Server sends:
return await Clients.Client(connectionInfo.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync<string>("Test", "Prefix", default);

Client Returns:
this.hubConnection.On<string>("Test", (prefix) => { return $"{prefix}Successful"; });

However I hit issues as soon as I send the parameters.  In this example I get:
Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value; 

Can anyone assist?
Thanks in advance

you can send an object instead of string !

I figured this out after lots of hair pulling (and maybe reading the documentation) :)
Server sends this and waits for the response. (This was never an issue)
return await Clients.Client(connectionInfo.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync<string>("Test", "Prefix", default);

The client was the issue (Note the second string in InkoveAsync<string, string>).  I also tidied it up into a separate function as in the real world this will perform some longer processing.
this.hubConnection.On<string, string>("Test", ReturnWithPrefix);

private string ReturnWthPrefix(string prefix) {
    return $"{prefix}Successful";
}

Hope this helps someone

You could try in the server hub, create a method
        public void ServerLog(string prefix)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}Successful");
        }

Then in the client you could let server execute this method when receive message
        hubConnection.On<string>("Test", (prefix) =>
        {
            hubConnection.InvokeAsync<string>("ServerLog", prefix);
        });


Thanks for responding.  I finally figure it out and have posted my solution.
